# % area of a raster file inside a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am trying calculate % area a raster is inside a polygon. I have the raster file as ASCII grid and polygon enclosing that grid. How can i calculate % area of a raster file inside a polygon in QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

Using inbuilt Zonal Statistics Tools in QGIS you can calculate the count of pixels of raster file inside a polygon.

Once you get that, then I think it will be easy for you to calculate the percentage area inside the polygon.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Chetan, I have managed to count the pixels in the raster, now what about calculating the area of the polygon? is there any built in command I can use?

Comment: @syed what i understand is if you know the resolution of your raster, area can be calculated by multiplying it with the number of pixels. It's the same for intersecting area of polygon as well.

Comment: You use the $area function in field calculator.